# maintain session between two pages in jsp having no relation

Tags: java, jsp, session

Hi guys i'm having a very weird problem that forced me to ask here

well i'm having two pages say register and validate .
on register page i'm setting values in session and wanted them on other page i.e validate page so can i access those values.

I tried to access but not getting proper results.

Is there any other way i can do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

session set

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
User_Registration urbean=new User_Registration();
urbean.setUser_mobile(userMobile);
urbean.setUser_email(userEmail);
urbean.setUser_name(userName);
urbean.setUser_country(usercountry);
session.setAttribute("userbean",urbean);
```

session get

```
  HttpSession session =request.getSession(); //also tried to getSession(true)
  System.out.println("session---"+session);

  //getting error at this point getUsr_mobile is not defined      
   System.out.println(session.getAttribute("userbean").getUser_mobile()));
```

I have to hit these links separately in my android program and i cant maintain any reponse.sendredirect() or any redirection method.

Comment: downvoter please comment for downvotes

Comment: Providing the pages are in the same application, the session would be shared.  Please include code to show how you're setting and getting the values

Comment: yeah the pages are in the same application.

Comment: RemoteCodeInspectionException caused by NoClassDefFoundError Message: Could not initialize class net.my.body.mind.util.ReadMindRemotely.class

Comment: yeah it is returning null so what i do for that

Comment: i tried session.getAttribute("urbean") but it is giving error.

Comment: Are you sure that your HTTP client is sending the session token in every request?  Browsers will do this automatically with cookies (usually JSESSIONID).   If you're using some HTTP thing on Android, make sure the first request captures the session token, and subsequent requests supply the token (again, usually JSESSIONID cookie).   Look at the HTTP headers.=

Comment: Also, yeah... you're not retrieving the bean you put in as "userbean" in the second code snippet.   That's not going to work, obviously.

Comment: yeah @JoshuaDavis  i m using HTTP client maintaining a status code .on hitting register page if i get a status code say 123 i have to hit on validate page and the data i have set on register page ,i wanted that on validate page.

Comment: can anyone tell why i'm getting downvotes for this .

Comment: @A5l-lE5 I'm not talking about the HTTP status code, I'm talking about the cookies in the header.   Servlet engines typically use a cookie called JSESSIONID to associate a request with a given HttpSession object.   This is one way we can access objects across multiple requests.   I think you are getting downvotes because the question is not well defined, and there are (perhaps very obvious) errors in the way HttpSession is being used in the code snippets.   I don't usually downvote questions personally.   Mostly just answers that are just plain incorrect.   Others may feel differently.

Comment: Anyhow... glad you've solved your problem.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `setAttribute` uses the key `"userbean"`, then your call to `getAttribute` uses `urbean.getUser_mobile()`.

Unless `urbean.getUser_mobile()` returns `"userbean"` then `getAttribute` will return `null`.

Given the code setting the attribute is:

```
session.setAttribute("userbean", urbean);
```

The code to get the attribute should be:

```
User_Registration urbean = (User_Registration)session.getAttribute("userbean")
```

You have to use the same key to *get* that you used to *set*...

Comment: yeah it worked ,i m getting bean data but wanted the value of the getUser_mobile i have set in register so how can i get i m getting error in that.

Comment: Once you've got the bean, just call the getter `getUser_mobile`

Answer (score 0):

Your are creating a new object

```
User_Registration urbean = new User_Registration();
```

it means you are creating a new instance.

You can use `session.setAttribute();` in order to set and

```
session.getAttribute();
```

to retrieve the values

Comment: but when i m using session.getAttribute("userbean").getUser_mobile() m getting error

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem by type casting the data to that bean.

```
    User_Registration urbean =new User_Registration();
    urbean=(User_Registration)session.getAttribute("userbean");
    System.out.println(urBean.getUser_mobile());
```